# Sorting items inside an anchor

Tags: knockout.js, bootstrap-sortable

I'm using the Bootstrap-sortable library, and knockout.js to bind the data. I want to sort

My code looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped" data-toggle="table" data-height="350">
    <thead>
        <th data-sortable="true">Subject</th>
        <th data-sortable="true">Deadline</th>
        <th data-sortable="true">toCompanyName</th>
        <th data-sortable="true">toContactName</th>
        <th data-sortable="true">toEmployeeName</th>
    </thead>

<tbody id="ulTasks" data-bind="foreach: activities">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a data-bind="attr: { href: todoLink }">
                    <span data-bind="text: subject"></span>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a data-bind="attr: { href: todoLink }">
                    <span data-bind="text: deadline"></span>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a data-bind="attr: { href: toCompanyLink }">
                    <span data-bind="text: toCompanyName"></span>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a data-bind="attr: { href: toContactLink }">
                    <span data-bind="text: toContactName"></span>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a data-bind="attr: { href: toEmployeeLink }">
                    <span data-bind="text: toEmployeeName"></span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>

</tbody>

</table>
```

The issue is that it doesn't sort well when the  is inside an anchor. On the same page there is also another table where I output the data directly inside a , and that one sorts like it should be.

Is it possible to sort items when they are inside an anchor?

Comment: There should be a conflict between knockout and bootstrap's JS . Why don't you  use knockout sort since you are using knockout?

Comment: Shouldn't you add a `data-value` attribute to the `<td>` element? I.e.: `data-bind="attr: { 'data-value': subject }"` etc.